# How can I make this dictionary object keep changing under the while statement?

Tags: python

Originally the question was meant to be solved using recursion, but anyway, I just decided to use the while statement.

If recursion is necessary, please let me know.

This is just a part of my code, but I guess the problem is that the dictionaries employee_state and visitor_state keep changing but the changes are not applied to the while statement.

How can I fix that?

Plus, if you need more of my codes to suggest an answer, just comment me.

```
def order_process(self):

    employee_state={}
    visitor_state={}

    for employee in self.employees:
        employee_state[employee]=employee.state
    for visitor in self.visitors:
        visitor_state[visitor]=visitor.state

    while WAITING in employee_state.values() and ARRIVAL in visitor_state.values():
        print(employee_state)
        print(visitor_state)
        for visitor in self.visitors:
            for employee in self.employees:
                if employee.state == WAITING:
                    if visitor.state == ARRIVAL:
                        employee.cook(visitor)

                        employee_state[employee] = employee.state
                        visitor_state[visitor] = visitor.state
```

Comment: What is the python version in use here?

Comment: Well, 3.6, if that's your question:)

Comment: That was my question https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/stdtypes.html#dict-views shows you that the dict_view ( aka the .values() ) gives you " They provide a dynamic view on the dictionary’s entries, which means that when the dictionary changes, the view reflects these changes." so its being reevaluated. So maybe the issue may be in the logic being used.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A quick and easy fix would be to change the `while` statement to simply be `while True:` and then at the end of the `while` block, add the following conditional

```
if WAITING not in employee_state.values() and ARRIVAL not in visitor_state.values():
    break
```

Comment: Simple but enough for me :)